# Node not redirecting to Page Not found 404

Tags: node.js, node-request

If I go to http://localhost:4000/asdfasd I should be seeing my page not found and my console.log in the server, but I don't see either or.

**APP.JS**

```
const EXPRESS = require('express');
const BODY_PARSER = require('body-parser');
const PATH = require('path');

const APP = EXPRESS();

const ADMIN_ROUTES = require('./routes/admin');
const SHOP_ROUTES = require('./routes/shop');

APP.use(BODY_PARSER.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

APP.use('/admin', ADMIN_ROUTES);
APP.use(SHOP_ROUTES);

APP.use((req, res, next) => {
  console.log('page not found');
  res
    .status(404)
    .sendFile(PATH.join(__dirname, '../', 'views', 'not-found.html'));
});

APP.listen(4000);
```

Comment: You might need to change `APP.use(SHOP_ROUTES);` to `APP.use('/shop', SHOP_ROUTES);`. Is there a route in your shop API that looks like `router.get('/:word', callback)`?

Comment: @khan that worked, but what about if I want to do my '/' to be displaying my shop? and no I don't ahve a dynamic route

Comment: Then you do `APP.use('/', SHOP_ROUTES)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Example code](https://github.com/ydhan18/stack-overflow-express-page-not-found/blob/master/server/routes/shop.js)

---

Express is not sending `not-found.html` because something higher up in your pipeline is handling your GET request to `/asdfasd`.

In your situation, `APP.use(SHOP_ROUTES)` is handling your request because all requests, excluding those that start with `/admin`, are first being sent to `SHOP_ROUTES`.

Here are some cases demonstrating why you do not see `not-found.html`:

---

> **Case 1:** You are using `router.use()` in your shop router and it is handling the request.

In this example:

**/routes/shop.js**

```
router.use((req, res, next) => res.send('Something'))
```

A request to `/asdfasd` will display the word *"Something"* on the page. Express will not go further down the pipeline because the request has been handled already.

---

> **Case 2:** You have an asynchronous function inside your shop router that does not use `next()`.

For example, if you are making a call to some API:

**/routes/shop.js**

```
// request-promise is an HTTP request client that returns a promise
const rp = require('request-promise')

router.use((req, res, next) => {
    rp.get('https://myapi.com/users')
        .then(response => res.json(response))
        .catch()
})
```

and your API request returns a status code of 400+ or 500+, your request is essentially stuck inside of this `router.use()` because you did not tell Express how to handle bad requests.

You would have to use the `next` function as a callback inside of your `.catch()`:

```
router.use((req, res, next) => {
    rp.get('https://myapi.com/users')
        .then(response => res.json(response))
        .catch(next)
})
```

---

> **Case 3:** You have a dynamic route inside of your shop router, ex. `/:word`.

If in your `SHOP_ROUTES`, you have a dynamic route, like the one below:

**/routes/shop.js**

```
router.get('/:word', (req, res, next) => res.send(req.params.word))
```

Any request to `/` that is not already handled by a preceding route will be handled by this one.